Apparmor config to allow postfix usage by php-fpm
I've configured an Ubuntu 24.04 with Apache, php-fpm and apparmor
The config works EXCEPT php-fpm is not allowed to use postfix so no e-mail could be sent through website.
Postfix itself works outside php-fpm
It gives me this log when I try
kernel: audit: type=1400 audit: apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="php-fpm//HATNAME" name="/home/USER/www/test-email.php"comm="php-fpm8.3" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1002 ouid=0

I'm out of ideas to solve it.
This is the part of my config related to this
/etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm
abi <abi/4.0>,

include <tunables/global>

profile php-fpm /usr/sbin/php-fpm* flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  include <abstractions/base>
  include <abstractions/nameservice>
  include <abstractions/php-worker>
  include <abstractions/php>
  include <abstractions/postfix-common>
  include if exists <local/php-fpm>
  include if exists <php-fpm.d>
  ...
  change_profile -> php-fpm//**,

}

/etc/apparmor.d/local/php-fpm
  capability chown,
  capability dac_override,
  capability kill,
  capability net_admin,
  capability setgid,
  capability setuid,

  deny / rw,

  signal receive peer=php-fpm//**,
  signal receive set=kill peer=php-fpm//**,
  signal receive set=quit peer=php-fpm//**,
  signal receive set=term peer=php-fpm//**,
  signal send peer=php-fpm//**,
  signal send set=kill peer=php-fpm//**,
  signal send set=quit peer=php-fpm//**,
  signal send set=term peer=php-fpm//**,

  ptrace trace peer=php-fpm,
  ptrace trace peer=php-fpm//*,
  ...

  /etc/php{,5,7,8}/** r,
  /proc/*/net/tcp r,
  /proc/*/net/tcp6 r,
  /proc/loadavg r,
  /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease r,
  /proc/uptime r,
  /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock rw,
  /run/php/php-fpm-*.sock rw,
  /usr/bin/dash mrix,
  /usr/bin/grep mrix,
  /usr/bin/netstat mrix,
  /usr/bin/uptime mrix,
  /usr/sbin/php-fpm* rix,
  /usr/sbin/postdrop Px,
  /usr/sbin/sendmail Px,
  /usr/sbin/postfix Px,
  /{,var/}run/utmp rk,
  @{PROC}/@{pid}/attr/{apparmor/,}current rw,
  @{run}/php{,-fpm}/php*-fpm.pid rw,
  @{run}/php{,-fpm}/php*-fpm.sock rwlk,
  owner /etc/group r,
  ...
  owner /run/systemd/notify w,

/etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm.d/HATNAME
  ^HATNAME flags=(attach_disconnected) {
    include <abstractions/base>
    include <abstractions/nameservice>
    include <abstractions/openssl>
    include <abstractions/php-worker>
    include <abstractions/php>
    include <abstractions/postfix-common>
    include <abstractions/ssl_certs>
    include <abstractions/ubuntu-konsole>
    include <abstractions/user-tmp>
    include <abstractions/web-data>

    include "/etc/apparmor.d/local/php-fpm"
    ...
    owner /home/USERNAME/www/** rw,
  }

As you can see abstractions/postfix-common is included
So does /usr/sbin/postfix which is also allowed
As I'm using hats, I'm unable to debug with aa-logprof command
Do you have an idea of what's wrong ? If not, do you know how I could debug it as aa-logprof doesn' work in such situation ?

I finally succeed. The instruction:
deny / rw,

in /etc/apparmor.d/local/php-fpm was preventing me to make a proper debug. I've temporary commented it which has allowed me to see the real errors.
I had to add this (probably too large but it's better than nothing):
/usr/sbin/postfix mrix,
/var/spool/postfix/** mrwix,

and uncomment the global deny.
